# Leaflet Vue 3 Error (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is undefined)

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

i receive this error and noting loaded

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is undefined
    Ye vue-leaflet.es.js:46
    setup vue-leaflet.es.js:1205
    callWithErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155
    callWithAsyncErrorHandling runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164
    __weh runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2684
    flushPostFlushCbs runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:341
    flushJobs runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:395
    promise callback*queueFlush runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:280
    queuePostFlushCb runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:302
    queueEffectWithSuspense runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1576
    scheduler runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1798
    triggerEffect reactivity.esm-bundler.js:394
    triggerEffects reactivity.esm-bundler.js:384
    triggerRefValue reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1000
    node_modules chunk-LQ5UJQYN.js:1429
    triggerEffect reactivity.esm-bundler.js:394
    triggerEffects reactivity.esm-bundler.js:379
    triggerRefValue reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1000
    node_modules chunk-LQ5UJQYN.js:1429
    triggerEffect reactivity.esm-bundler.js:394
    triggerEffects reactivity.esm-bundler.js:379
    triggerRefValue reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1000
    set value reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1045
    finalizeNavigation vue-router.mjs:3324
    pushWithRedirect vue-router.mjs:3197
    promise callback*pushWithRedirect vue-router.mjs:3164
    push vue-router.mjs:3089
    install vue-router.mjs:3520
    use runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4349
    <anonymous> main.ts:10
.
.
.
.
```

mys code is like this

```
                    <div class="map">
                        <l-map ref="map" v-model:zoom="zoom" :center="center">
                            <l-tile-layer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" layer-type="base"
                                name="OpenStreetMap"></l-tile-layer>
                        </l-map>
                    </div>
```

```
/* import leaflet */
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { LMap, LTileLayer } from "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet";
/* leaflet */
const zoom = ref(2)
const center = ref([47.41322, -1.219482])
```

can anybody explain whats wrong with it

i used example at https://github.com/vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet offical github bet it got above error

Answer (score 9):

Adding `:use-global-leaflet="false"` to the `l-map` component should solve the issue. For further information, please refer to [this issue](https://github.com/vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet/issues/289#issuecomment-1476702901).